# Ingress - default backend - 404 on TLS

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, rancher

I'm using Rancher 2.4.7 to deploy applications on customer's environments.
I successfully created a new cluster for a production environment however whenever I create an Ingress resource with a specific hostname (the certificate is valid) : I get the `default backend - 404` message when accessing my applications.

If I create an Ingress resource using the embed `xip.io` hostname, I can access my applications like it's supposed to.

I tried creating my resource using `kubectl` and the Rancher UI.

When getting the `default backend - 404` error, no logs are registered on my deployment.

Deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        workload.user.cattle.io/workloadselector: deployment-default-nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: nginx
          protocol: TCP
        resources: {}
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
          capabilities: {}
          privileged: false
          readOnlyRootFilesystem: false
          runAsNonRoot: false
        stdin: true
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        tty: true
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
```

Service :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
  - name: nginx
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    workload.user.cattle.io/workloadselector: deployment-default-nginx
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
```

Ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: nginx
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - mydomain.com
    secretName: mycertificate
```

Any thoughts what is wrong?

EDIT:

I'm using nginx-ingress shipped with Rancher. I'm not using any Cloud Provider. I installed a RKE Cluster using the Rancher UI.

Ingress controller logs:

```
I0111 16:13:02.868872       6 flags.go:204] Watching for Ingress class: nginx 
W0111 16:13:02.869187       6 flags.go:249] SSL certificate chain completion is disabled (--enable-ssl-chain-completion=false) 
W0111 16:13:02.869225       6 client_config.go:543] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work. 
I0111 16:13:02.869357       6 main.go:220] Creating API client for https://10.43.0.1:443 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
NGINX Ingress controller 
  Release:       0.32.0 
  Build:         git-29dd9760f 
  Repository:    https://github.com/rancher/ingress-nginx.git 
  nginx version: nginx/1.17.10 
 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 
I0111 16:13:02.879836       6 main.go:264] Running in Kubernetes cluster version v1.18 (v1.18.6) - git (clean) commit dff82dc0de47299ab66c83c626e08b245ab19037 - platform linux/amd64 
I0111 16:13:02.884023       6 main.go:94] Validated ingress-nginx/default-http-backend as the default backend. 
I0111 16:13:03.022518       6 main.go:105] SSL fake certificate created /etc/ingress-controller/ssl/default-fake-certificate.pem 
I0111 16:13:03.023350       6 main.go:113] Enabling new Ingress features available since Kubernetes v1.18 
E0111 16:13:03.024271       6 main.go:122] Unexpected error searching IngressClass: ingressclasses.networking.k8s.io "nginx" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:ingress-nginx:nginx-ingress-serviceaccount" cannot get resource "ingressclasses" in API group "networking.k8s.io" at the cluster scope 
W0111 16:13:03.024285       6 main.go:125] No IngressClass resource with name nginx found. Only annotation will be used. 
I0111 16:13:03.060623       6 nginx.go:263] Starting NGINX Ingress controller 
I0111 16:13:03.077607       6 event.go:278] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"ConfigMap", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"tcp-services", UID:"eb5e7318-e99c-428f-82a0-4321925fdc4e", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"610", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'CREATE' ConfigMap ingress-nginx/tcp-services 
I0111 16:13:03.077660       6 event.go:278] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"ConfigMap", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"udp-services", UID:"91590425-b422-4c4b-829d-a0be04973a9d", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"611", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'CREATE' ConfigMap ingress-nginx/udp-services 
I0111 16:13:03.077677       6 event.go:278] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"ConfigMap", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"nginx-configuration", UID:"20b82b4a-e536-4a63-9fd2-20e17489b1ab", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"607", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'CREATE' ConfigMap ingress-nginx/nginx-configuration 
I0111 16:13:04.168739       6 backend_ssl.go:66] Adding Secret "default/mycertificate" to the local store 
I0111 16:13:04.261564       6 nginx.go:307] Starting NGINX process 
I0111 16:13:04.261672       6 leaderelection.go:242] attempting to acquire leader lease  ingress-nginx/ingress-controller-leader-nginx... 
I0111 16:13:04.262436       6 controller.go:139] Configuration changes detected, backend reload required. 
I0111 16:13:04.363051       6 leaderelection.go:252] successfully acquired lease ingress-nginx/ingress-controller-leader-nginx 
I0111 16:13:04.363157       6 status.go:86] new leader elected: nginx-ingress-controller-5dwhm 
I0111 16:13:04.385580       6 controller.go:155] Backend successfully reloaded. 
I0111 16:13:04.385608       6 controller.go:164] Initial sync, sleeping for 1 second. 
E0111 16:14:14.950751       6 reflector.go:382] k8s.io/ingress-nginx/internal/ingress/controller/store/store.go:161: Failed to watch *v1.Pod: Get "https://10.43.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/ingress-nginx/pods?allowWatchBookmarks=true&labelSelector=app%3Dingress-nginx%2Ccontroller-revision-hash%3D55dd558cd5%2Cpod-template-generation%3D1&resourceVersion=1028734&timeout=9m32s&timeoutSeconds=572&watch=true": dial tcp 10.43.0.1:443: connect: connection refused 
E0111 16:14:14.950798       6 reflector.go:382] k8s.io/ingress-nginx/internal/ingress/controller/store/store.go:159: Failed to watch *v1.Service: Get "https://10.43.0.1:443/api/v1/services?allowWatchBookmarks=true&resourceVersion=1028611&timeout=5m1s&timeoutSeconds=301&watch=true": dial tcp 10.43.0.1:443: connect: connection refused 
E0111 16:14:14.950816       6 reflector.go:382] k8s.io/ingress-nginx/internal/ingress/controller/store/store.go:157: Failed to watch *v1.Secret: Get "https://10.43.0.1:443/api/v1/secrets?allowWatchBookmarks=true&resourceVersion=1028785&timeout=9m23s&timeoutSeconds=563&watch=true": dial tcp 10.43.0.1:443: connect: connection refused 
E0111 16:14:14.950847       6 reflector.go:382] k8s.io/ingress-nginx/internal/ingress/controller/store/store.go:182: Failed to watch *v1beta1.Ingress: Get "https://10.43.0.1:443/apis/networking.k8s.io/v1beta1/ingresses?allowWatchBookmarks=true&resourceVersion=1028611&timeout=8m58s&timeoutSeconds=538&watch=true": dial tcp 10.43.0.1:443: connect: connection refused 
E0111 16:14:14.951438       6 reflector.go:382] k8s.io/ingress-nginx/internal/ingress/controller/store/store.go:160: Failed to watch *v1.ConfigMap: Get "https://10.43.0.1:443/api/v1/configmaps?allowWatchBookmarks=true&resourceVersion=1028928&timeout=9m58s&timeoutSeconds=598&watch=true": dial tcp 10.43.0.1:443: connect: connection refused 
E0111 16:14:14.951936       6 reflector.go:382] k8s.io/ingress-nginx/internal/ingress/controller/store/store.go:158: Failed to watch *v1.Endpoints: Get "https://10.43.0.1:443/api/v1/endpoints?allowWatchBookmarks=true&resourceVersion=1028926&timeout=9m48s&timeoutSeconds=588&watch=true": dial tcp 10.43.0.1:443: connect: connection refused 
I0112 09:02:55.888418       6 controller.go:139] Configuration changes detected, backend reload required. 
I0112 09:02:55.969141       6 controller.go:155] Backend successfully reloaded. 
I0112 09:22:55.591923       6 controller.go:139] Configuration changes detected, backend reload required. 
I0112 09:22:55.591920       6 event.go:278] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"default", Name:"nginx", UID:"5121fa4a-a2c1-445a-a65a-da5ad64088f1", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"1173601", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'CREATE' Ingress default/nginx 
I0112 09:22:55.676508       6 controller.go:155] Backend successfully reloaded. 
I0112 09:23:04.372633       6 status.go:275] updating Ingress default/nginx status from [] to [{10.107.129.176 }] 
I0112 09:23:04.380700       6 event.go:278] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"default", Name:"nginx", UID:"5121fa4a-a2c1-445a-a65a-da5ad64088f1", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"1173626", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'UPDATE' Ingress default/nginx 
I0112 09:23:04.388779       6 event.go:278] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"default", Name:"nginx", UID:"5121fa4a-a2c1-445a-a65a-da5ad64088f1", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"1173628", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'UPDATE' Ingress default/nginx 
I0112 09:23:04.402679       6 event.go:278] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"default", Name:"nginx", UID:"5121fa4a-a2c1-445a-a65a-da5ad64088f1", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"1173629", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'UPDATE' Ingress default/nginx 
I0112 09:23:07.714377       6 controller.go:139] Configuration changes detected, backend reload required. 
I0112 09:23:07.791810       6 controller.go:155] Backend successfully reloaded. 
10.117.131.141 - - [12/Jan/2021:09:23:11 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 414 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36" 504 0.006 [default-nginx-80] [] 10.42.0.168:80 612 0.004 200 0bb06b53bbc47c83854cf8e19fde2e4a 
I0112 09:24:06.033945       6 controller.go:139] Configuration changes detected, backend reload required. 
I0112 09:24:06.114217       6 controller.go:155] Backend successfully reloaded. 
E0112 09:35:32.853089       6 reflector.go:382] k8s.io/ingress-nginx/internal/ingress/controller/store/store.go:161: Failed to watch *v1.Pod: Get "https://10.43.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/ingress-nginx/pods?allowWatchBookmarks=true&labelSelector=app%3Dingress-nginx%2Ccontroller-revision-hash%3D55dd558cd5%2Cpod-template-generation%3D1&resourceVersion=1173526&timeout=8m3s&timeoutSeconds=483&watch=true": dial tcp 10.43.0.1:443: connect: connection refused 
E0112 09:35:32.853089       6 reflector.go:382] k8s.io/ingress-nginx/internal/ingress/controller/store/store.go:160: Failed to watch *v1.ConfigMap: Get "https://10.43.0.1:443/api/v1/configmaps?allowWatchBookmarks=true&resourceVersion=1175379&timeout=6m4s&timeoutSeconds=364&watch=true": dial tcp 10.43.0.1:443: connect: connection refused 
E0112 09:35:32.853156       6 reflector.go:382] k8s.io/ingress-nginx/internal/ingress/controller/store/store.go:182: Failed to watch *v1beta1.Ingress: Get "https://10.43.0.1:443/apis/networking.k8s.io/v1beta1/ingresses?allowWatchBookmarks=true&resourceVersion=1173916&timeout=6m15s&timeoutSeconds=375&watch=true": dial tcp 10.43.0.1:443: connect: connection refused 
E0112 09:35:32.853566       6 reflector.go:382] k8s.io/ingress-nginx/internal/ingress/controller/store/store.go:159: Failed to watch *v1.Service: Get "https://10.43.0.1:443/api/v1/services?allowWatchBookmarks=true&resourceVersion=1173495&timeout=9m31s&timeoutSeconds=571&watch=true": dial tcp 10.43.0.1:443: connect: connection refused 
E0112 09:35:32.854106       6 reflector.go:382] k8s.io/ingress-nginx/internal/ingress/controller/store/store.go:158: Failed to watch *v1.Endpoints: Get "https://10.43.0.1:443/api/v1/endpoints?allowWatchBookmarks=true&resourceVersion=1175377&timeout=6m14s&timeoutSeconds=374&watch=true": dial tcp 10.43.0.1:443: connect: connection refused 
E0112 09:35:32.854378       6 reflector.go:382] k8s.io/ingress-nginx/internal/ingress/controller/store/store.go:157: Failed to watch *v1.Secret: Get "https://10.43.0.1:443/api/v1/secrets?allowWatchBookmarks=true&resourceVersion=1173561&timeout=9m27s&timeoutSeconds=567&watch=true": dial tcp 10.43.0.1:443: connect: connection refused 
E0112 09:35:36.334273       6 reflector.go:382] k8s.io/ingress-nginx/internal/ingress/controller/store/store.go:157: Failed to watch *v1.Secret: unknown (get secrets) 
E0112 09:35:36.334349       6 reflector.go:382] k8s.io/ingress-nginx/internal/ingress/controller/store/store.go:160: Failed to watch *v1.ConfigMap: unknown (get configmaps) 
E0112 09:35:36.334520       6 reflector.go:382] k8s.io/ingress-nginx/internal/ingress/controller/store/store.go:159: Failed to watch *v1.Service: unknown (get services) 
E0112 09:35:36.334538       6 reflector.go:382] k8s.io/ingress-nginx/internal/ingress/controller/store/store.go:158: Failed to watch *v1.Endpoints: unknown (get endpoints) 
I0112 10:18:11.687109       6 controller.go:139] Configuration changes detected, backend reload required. 
I0112 10:18:11.775731       6 controller.go:155] Backend successfully reloaded. 
I0112 10:48:25.950829       6 controller.go:139] Configuration changes detected, backend reload required. 
I0112 10:48:26.033626       6 controller.go:155] Backend successfully reloaded. 
W0112 10:49:21.912963       6 controller.go:909] Service "default/nginx" does not have any active Endpoint. 
W0112 11:05:53.875160       6 controller.go:909] Service "default/nginx" does not have any active Endpoint. 
I0112 11:05:53.875312       6 controller.go:139] Configuration changes detected, backend reload required. 
I0112 11:05:53.942794       6 controller.go:155] Backend successfully reloaded. 
I0112 11:05:53.990374       6 event.go:278] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"default", Name:"nginx", UID:"5121fa4a-a2c1-445a-a65a-da5ad64088f1", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"1188099", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'DELETE' Ingress default/nginx 
I0112 11:05:57.208715       6 controller.go:139] Configuration changes detected, backend reload required. 
I0112 11:05:57.297730       6 controller.go:155] Backend successfully reloaded. 
I0112 11:06:15.724049       6 event.go:278] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"default", Name:"nginx", UID:"c230bb3e-7e0c-4ffa-b8a3-24e437a11b7c", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"1188154", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'CREATE' Ingress default/nginx 
W0112 11:06:15.725433       6 controller.go:909] Service "default/nginx" does not have any active Endpoint. 
I0112 11:06:15.725612       6 controller.go:139] Configuration changes detected, backend reload required. 
I0112 11:06:15.808897       6 controller.go:155] Backend successfully reloaded. 
I0112 11:07:04.375801       6 status.go:275] updating Ingress default/nginx status from [] to [{10.107.129.176 }] 
I0112 11:07:04.386737       6 event.go:278] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"default", Name:"nginx", UID:"c230bb3e-7e0c-4ffa-b8a3-24e437a11b7c", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"1188268", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'UPDATE' Ingress default/nginx 
W0112 11:07:04.386900       6 controller.go:909] Service "default/nginx" does not have any active Endpoint. 
I0112 11:07:04.399808       6 event.go:278] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"default", Name:"nginx", UID:"c230bb3e-7e0c-4ffa-b8a3-24e437a11b7c", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"1188270", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'UPDATE' Ingress default/nginx 
W0112 11:07:07.720456       6 controller.go:909] Service "default/nginx" does not have any active Endpoint. 
W0112 12:37:09.436273       6 controller.go:909] Service "default/nginx" does not have any active Endpoint. 
I0112 12:37:09.436524       6 event.go:278] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"default", Name:"nginx", UID:"c230bb3e-7e0c-4ffa-b8a3-24e437a11b7c", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"1200926", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'UPDATE' Ingress default/nginx 
W0112 12:37:32.812935       6 controller.go:909] Service "default/nginx" does not have any active Endpoint. 
W0112 12:37:43.751781       6 controller.go:909] Service "default/nginx" does not have any active Endpoint. 
W0112 12:37:47.085248       6 controller.go:909] Service "default/nginx" does not have any active Endpoint. 
W0112 13:29:48.126896       6 controller.go:909] Service "default/nginx" does not have any active Endpoint. 
I0112 13:29:48.127046       6 controller.go:139] Configuration changes detected, backend reload required. 
I0112 13:29:48.194086       6 controller.go:155] Backend successfully reloaded. 
W0112 13:34:18.155900       6 controller.go:909] Service "default/nginx" does not have any active Endpoint. 
I0112 13:34:18.156070       6 controller.go:139] Configuration changes detected, backend reload required. 
I0112 13:34:18.231656       6 controller.go:155] Backend successfully reloaded. 
W0112 13:50:31.577308       6 main.go:60] Protocol "HTTPS" is not a valid value for the backend-protocol annotation. Using HTTP as protocol 
W0112 13:50:31.578553       6 controller.go:909] Service "default/nginx" does not have any active Endpoint. 
W0112 13:50:50.699484       6 controller.go:909] Service "default/nginx" does not have any active Endpoint. 
W0112 14:34:11.399326       6 controller.go:909] Service "default/nginx" does not have any active Endpoint. 
I0112 14:34:11.399493       6 controller.go:139] Configuration changes detected, backend reload required. 
I0112 14:34:11.494728       6 controller.go:155] Backend successfully reloaded. 
W0112 14:35:04.385107       6 controller.go:909] Service "default/nginx" does not have any active Endpoint. 
W0112 14:35:07.718580       6 controller.go:909] Service "default/nginx" does not have any active Endpoint. 
I0112 14:35:07.718815       6 controller.go:139] Configuration changes detected, backend reload required. 
I0112 14:35:07.819621       6 controller.go:155] Backend successfully reloaded. 
W0112 14:35:11.052037       6 controller.go:909] Service "default/nginx" does not have any active Endpoint. 
W0112 14:35:33.306202       6 controller.go:909] Service "default/nginx" does not have any active Endpoint. 
W0112 14:37:02.428966       6 controller.go:822] Error obtaining Endpoints for Service "default/nginx": no object matching key "default/nginx" in local store 
I0112 14:37:02.429111       6 controller.go:139] Configuration changes detected, backend reload required. 
I0112 14:37:02.493923       6 controller.go:155] Backend successfully reloaded. 
I0112 14:37:05.762583       6 controller.go:139] Configuration changes detected, backend reload required. 
I0112 14:37:05.859639       6 controller.go:155] Backend successfully reloaded. 
10.117.131.141 - - [12/Jan/2021:14:37:07 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 414 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36" 618 0.002 [default-nginx-80] [] 10.42.0.168:80 612 0.000 200 4e6feb07a8d5e16a9d2592272ca338fd 
I0112 15:24:28.246019       6 controller.go:139] Configuration changes detected, backend reload required. 
I0112 15:24:28.316464       6 controller.go:155] Backend successfully reloaded. 
I0112 15:25:31.398134       6 event.go:278] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"default", Name:"nginx", UID:"c230bb3e-7e0c-4ffa-b8a3-24e437a11b7c", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"1224608", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'UPDATE' Ingress default/nginx
```

Comment: How is your ingress-controller exposed? Have you installed it yourself or do you use the included nginx-ingress that's shipped with Rancher? Do you even installed a RKE-Cluster or do you use a Cloud-Provider, which maybe has placed a LoadBalancer in front of your cluster?

Comment: I'm using nginx-ingress shipped with Rancher. I'm not using any Cloud Provider. I installed a RKE Cluster using the Rancher UI.

Answer (score 1):

```
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    serviceName: ingress-nginx-controller
    servicePort: 80
```

Before `rules` add this

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I am able to understand since it would require some RnD.
Meanwhile, you can checkout the ingress config that I used on my project :

> **Note:** What version of Ingress I used and also the **annotations** for it

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/default-backend: ingress-nginx-controller
    ## tells ingress to check for regex in the config file
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS";
      add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true;
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: "PUT, GET, POST, OPTIONS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/from-to-www-redirect: "true"  ## IMPORTANT

spec:
  ## TLS config
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - www.mydomain.com
        - mydomain.com
      secretName: cultor-test-tls
  ## our custom routing rules
  rules:
    - host: www.mydomain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/upload/?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: aws-srv
              servicePort: 3000
          - path: /api/project/?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: project-srv
              servicePort: 3000
          - path: /api/profile/?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: profile-srv
              servicePort: 3000
          - path: /api/users/?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: auth-srv
              servicePort: 3000
          - path: /?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: client-srv
              servicePort: 3000
```

## Important

Make sure you've tried accessing the domain **with and without WWW** and add this in your config as shown above

```yaml
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/from-to-www-redirect: "true"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the annotations did not solve the issue. I already tested with "www" but the result is the same. Do you need more informations on the issue ?

Comment: Did you change the apiVersion?

Answer (score 0):

Your service and deployment labels are not matching. That's why any of the requests for this service are not finding the backend and there is nothing to respond to these requests. For service you use:

```
selector:
    name: nginx
```

When for deployment you use:

```
  labels:
    app: nginx
```

You have to change labels in either of the deployment so they will match.

Comment: I'm sorry, that's on me. I cleaned the yaml for lisibility before posting them as Rancher adds a lot of metadata, I must have deleted/edit the wrong lines. I'll will edit them in my original post. Even though, my deployment and service are matching because it is working fine when using ingress without a specific hostname.

Comment: Can you check logs of ingress-controller and add it to your question? https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/installation/resources/troubleshooting/#default-backend-404 Also you can check nginx.conf `kubectl exec -it <nginx-controller> -- cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf | grep ssl_client_certificate -A 5 -B 5` and post it in answer.

Comment: I added the ingress controller logs to my original post. I don't get anything from your command line.